# How to expand and compress an image with scroll down and scroll up respectively in a smooth way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  an element as below :-

```
<div class='bulb rellax' data-rellax-speed="-2">
   <img  src="bulb.png" height="200" width="200"></img>
</div>
```

I am trying to gently expand it on scroll down and compress gently on scroll up. The element is placed on the extreme right side. The CSS is :-

```
.bulb{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:350px;
}
```

I have tried using the following Jquery but it doesn't help. How to reduce it on scroll up as well and make it a bit smooth.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var scroll_pos = 0;
$(document).scroll(function() {
  scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (scroll_pos > 150) {
    scroll_pos = 150;
  }
  $(".bulb").animate({
    width: (75 + 0.75 * scroll_pos) + "px"
  });
 });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: Updated please chek

Comment: Please have a look at this demo http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/zoom-hero-images-scroll